# storyboard UI change without programmer intervension

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode6, uistoryboard

A weird thing happens to me, the headline sums it up pretty well.
I have constraints on all the `UI` in custom `UITableViewCells`, they all of a sudden change without me touching xcode, and then i need to click "update frames" in order to return it to proper state.

any ideas?,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when there is a change in size classes,please check your size class as it indicated in attached image: [image]

Comment: that's not it. i develop for compact width and regular height only. size classes didn't change.